# How to create a Snap package for a software?

Tags: snap

I haven't found any easy to understand resource for absolute beginners who wish to package a software.

Let's take the example to package the latest release `2.5.0` of [Vokoscreen Screencast Recorder](http://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html) that is only available as `vokoscreen-2.5.0.tar.gz` but neither as a `.deb`, nor is there a PPA available.

What would the steps with the new Snap packaging format be to package this version as a `.snap` package for easy install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just unzip the file in a folder, add a snapcraft.yaml file and run `snapcraft snap`. snapcraft.yaml should probably look something like this:

```
name: vokoscreen
version: 0.1
summary: Vokoscreen screencast creator
description: >
  Vokoscreen is an easy to use screencast creator
  to record educational videos, live recordings of
  browser, installation, videoconferences, etc.

apps:
  vokoscreen:
    command: vokoscreen.run
```

Answer (score 4):

The [snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io/) website and [snap creation page](https://snapcraft.io/docs/creating-a-snap) is the definitive guide on how to snap a software program.

Comment: The "ubuntu developer website" URL is a link rot.

Comment: Maybe https://snapcraft.io/docs/creating-a-snap  (but that URL should be found at the provided snapcraft.io link)