# help me to fix distrupted installation oald8 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

common issue that upset me  :

```
./oald8-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libpangox-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when install libangox :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpangox-1.0-0:i386
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libpangox-1.0-0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpangox-1.0-0'
```

any idea to help me please

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libpangox shows it's found in 'universe', do you have it enabled?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: need i386 for installation, for amd64 it ok

Comment: No sorry, your issue is the :386   That package no-one declared as necessary so wasn't migrated to 20.04/focal, on any of the calls for packages required... https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/community-process-for-32-bit-compatibility/12598

Comment: back to 16.04 again?

Comment: Given 16.04 LTS hasn't that long left of supported life, I don't think that's a good long-term idea anyway, if you need it for production systems, it's worthwhile watching discussions such as the i386 packages on community.ubuntu.com, so you can raise you "*I need it for*.." issues there and you'd not likely end up with this issue, or be advised to `snap` your package on 16.04 so it'll work on any release into the future etc...

Comment: so  must wait for the packages?

Comment: It's somewhat late, but my last comment had what I'd suggest, ie. raising a *you need* request for the package to be built on i386 (it won't occur otherwise in the future; why Canonical announced the change well in advance calling for input & list of packages needed by end-users/enterprises) or re-package your need in another way (eg. snaps I mentioned)

Comment: go back to 16.04, and snap all packages what i  need, that right?

Comment: No I didn't mentioned 16.04 except saying I felt it was a bad idea, and in example of my secondary option (ie. snap option).  Snapping a package allows you to build a snap on a system where it works perfectly (eg. 16.04), and use that snap on 18.04/20.04 & in the future 22.04 (even other distros such as OpenSUSE after snap support is enabled/added).  It was an option I listed, my second (fallback) option actually  (opensuse used as example, can be any distro that has snap support)

Comment: how to snapping the package

Comment: That should be a different question (or look up https://askubuntu.com/questions/794044/how-to-create-a-snap-package-for-a-software)

Comment: can you help me to find libpangox-1.0-0:i386 that snap you mind